# Using Model name from Variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a variable which holds the model name like so

```
$fooTableName = 'foo_defs';
$fooModel = 'FooDefs';
```

Now I would like to insert in the DB using that model like so

```
$fooModel::insert([..foo..array...]);
```

Throws an error

> ```
> "message": "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$fooModel' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)",
> ```

Is it possible to do something like that? or will I be forced to use

```
DB::table('fooTableName')->insert([...foo...array...]);
```

If I do it in the latter way, the timestamps in the table are wrong. The `created_at` column is null and the `updated_at` has the value

**EDIT 1**

```
 $model =  CustomHelper::getNameSpace($this->tableNames[$i]);
 // $model => /var/www/html/erp/app/Models/sales/InvoiceDefs
 $model::insert($this->tableCollections[$this->tableNames[$i]]);
```

Most of them said that, it was namespace issue, so I have corrected it, but still it is throw error like

> "message": "Class '/var/www/html/erp/app/Models/sales/InvoiceDefs' not
>   found",

Comment: What you want to do is possible, but that syntax error is being caused my something else. You need to post more code.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code ... you might actually have a syntax error ....

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement? Your attempt makes me think that you have a situation where you would want to store records in tables based on certain situation or rules.

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes, it is storing records in the database, but the tables are always dynamic. For ex: I have 10 forms, all 10 forms store functionality I am trying to hit in one endpoint rather than 10 different endpoints i.e., creating a common function to store data from any form

Comment: @newUserName02, there are no syntax error for sure.

Comment: @Rehan ok, do all database tables have same columns?

Comment: @newUserName02 no, the array which I am trying to insert is also dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is using **model name as string**, you need to refactor your code as like below :

```
$fooModel = 'App\Models\FooDefs';
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one,

```
$fooModel = new FooDefs();
```

and then you can do the following also,

```
$fooModel->column1 = $value1;
$fooModel->column2 = $value2;
$fooModel->column2 = $value2;
$fooModel->save();
```

or

```
$fooModel->save([
    'column1' => $value1,
    'column2' => $value2,
    'column3' => $value3,    
])
```

**Edited answer**

```
$path = 'my\project\path\to\Models';
$fooModel = app($path.'\FooDefs');
$fooModel::save([
    'column1' => $value1,
    'column2' => $value2,
    'column3' => $value3,    
])
dd($fooModel ::all());
```

Try my edited answer.

Comment: the thing is that the Model names are dynamic, so I can explicitly says new FooDefs(), the model name is stored in a variable $fooModel;

Answer (score 1):

I have a same situation before and i have created the function to do this

```
function convertVariableToModelName($modelName='',$nameSpace='')
        {
            //if the given name space iin array the implode to string with \\
            if (is_array($nameSpace))
            {
                $nameSpace =  implode('\\', $nameSpace);
            }
            //by default laravel ships with name space App so while is $nameSpace is not passed considering the
            // model namespace as App
            if (empty($nameSpace) || is_null($nameSpace) || $nameSpace === "") 
            {                
               $modelNameWithNameSpace = "App".'\\'.$modelName;
            }
            //if you are using custom name space such as App\Models\Base\Country.php
            //$namespce must be ['App','Models','Base']
            if (is_array($nameSpace)) 
            {
                $modelNameWithNameSpace = $nameSpace.'\\'.$modelName;

            }
            //if you are passing Such as App in name space
            elseif (!is_array($nameSpace) && !empty($nameSpace) && !is_null($nameSpace) && $nameSpace !== "") 
            {
                $modelNameWithNameSpace = $nameSpace.'\\'.$modelName;

            }
            //if the class exist with current namespace convert to container instance.
            if (class_exists($modelNameWithNameSpace)) 
            {
                    // $currentModelWithNameSpace = Container::getInstance()->make($modelNameWithNameSpace);
                    // use Illuminate\Container\Container;
                    $currentModelWithNameSpace = app($modelNameWithNameSpace);
            }
            //else throw the class not found exception
            else
            {
                throw new \Exception("Unable to find Model : $modelName With NameSpace $nameSpace", E_USER_ERROR);
            }

            return $currentModelWithNameSpace;
        }
```

How To user it:

**Arguments**

> First Argument => Name of the Model
>
> Second Argument => Namespcce of the Model

For Example  we have the model name as `Post`

$postModel = convertVariableToModelName('Post');

```
dd($postModel::all());
```

Will returns all the values in the `posts` table

But in Some Situation You Model Will in the

**Custom  Namespace such as** `App\Models\Admin\User`

So this function is created to overcome that

```
$userModel = convertVariableToModelName('User',['App','Models','Admin']);

dd($userModel::all());
```

You are feel free to customize the function

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solutions gave me a start point. The issue was simple, there were no namespace.

Comment: **no problem. But in Some Situation i have moved my models to the custom namespace Because Somebody prefers to keep it in App\Models Folder.**  i have created to overcome that.If you think my answer is good then marks is as accepted

Comment: and i also hate being writing the code again and again. So i have created the function to overcome that

Answer (score 0):

When you have the name of class stored as string you can call method on that class by using the php method `call_user_func_array` like this

```
$class_name = "FooDefs";
call_user_func_array(array($class_name, "insert"), $data);
```

`$data` is an Array of data which will be past to the called function as arguments.

Just for simple advice It's will be **Good** if you save in the `$class_name` variable the **FQN** [Fully Qualified Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) of the class which is the `__NAMESPACE__` follow by the name of the class. For sample purpose FQN look like `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` which you can get when you save you use `User::class` I presume you have some User model. That will return the Fully Qualified Name of the User model will will be `App\User` in case of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $requests = $post['request']     // posting the data from view page
 $models =  "app\models".'\\'.$requests  //geting the model 
 $model = $models::findOne($referenceId) //fetching value from database
```

Comment: Hello Anisha, welcome to SO. Perhaps you should elaborate your answer and how is it helping OP's question.